# Redirection of electrical current

Tags: current, multimeter

Sorry if this is about the newbiest question on this site,

If I were to draw a graphite trace on a piece of paper (which from what I know would have some amount of resistance), and connect a multimeter and 9V battery to it as shown below:

[image: diagram]

Assuming that an electrical charge flows from - to + and takes the path of least resistance, how would I redirect the charge to go from contact A to contact B, instead of contact A to contact C (effectively shutting off the multimeter), without shorting out the 9V and putting it at risk of catching fire?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It would be more correct to say:

"How can I change the path of the current from flowing from point A to point C to flowing from point A to point B."

You would need to move the purple wire connected to the meter from point C to point B.

For current to flow, you need a closed completed path.  You can trace the path with your finger by starting at the battery's positive terminal, moving toward the meter, going through the meter, moving toward the graphite trace, moving through the graphite trace then moving back to the battery.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, is there a way to leave the wire from multimeter - to contact C connected, while adding some kind of switch connected to contact B, so that when the switch is closed, the charge flows through the switch to another device (an LED for instance)?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.  Just remember you need a closed completed path for current to flow.  You probably have more than 1 way to drive from home to work and back home again.  Both represent closed completed paths.  Circuits work the same way. You can have more than 1 closed completed path through a circuit.   By the way, you probably want to use the word "current" instead of "charge" to make your self clear to others when you talk about paths through circuits.

Answer (score 0):

> how would I redirect the charge to go from contact A to contact B, instead of contact A to contact C (effectively shutting off the multimeter),

Simply connect a wire from B back to the + terminal of the battery.

> without shorting out the 9V and putting it at risk of catching fire?

Make sure the resistance of the track from A to B is high enough that the battery can supply the current it demands, before you make the connection. A graphite line on a piece of paper isn't a very good resistor, so if the line from A to B is long enough, you won't have a problem.

> Assuming that an electrical charge flows from - to + and takes the path of least resistance,

This is two wrong assumptions in one sentence.

First, because electric current flows from higher potentials to lower potentials. When a negative charge flows from left to right, we call that "current flowing from right to left". It was an arbitrary choice made by the early researches in electrical physics before they knew that the charge carriers in metals are negatively charged, and we're not going to change it now.

Second, because current flows in all paths of a parallel circuit. It flows in each path in proportion to the conductance of that path, so if there is large difference in conductance, one path will take the large majority of the current. This is a common situation, and it's what we mean when we say "current takes the path of least resistance". But still, current flows at least in small amounts in all paths of a parallel circuit.

Comment: So in theory, something **similar** to this would be a better idea? [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mptvvjpdk9fymwh/newdiagram.png?dl=1)

Comment: It depends what you're trying to accomplish, Why not get a NO switch and put it in series with the ammeter?

Comment: If I wanted to press the button, the current would flow through the resistor (generating heat) instead of flowing through the multimeter, and without exploding the 9V through a short circuit?

Comment: Is the meter an ammeter or a voltmeter?

Comment: The way I'm using it right now, it's functioning as a voltmeter.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly, you could represent what you have drawn as this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fG2CIQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R is an arbitrary number that will depend on how wide the traces are and other factors. Let's assume R = 100K for the sake of argument. I have assumed the meter is in voltage mode and it has an input resistance of 10M ohms.

Then you have 1.2M in series with 10M across the battery, and the meter would read about 7.4V.

If you short B to the + terminal on the battery, the meter reading will go down to about 5.5V (look up Thevenin equivalent and voltage divider if you want to know how to analyze it). Some current flows through terminal B and some through terminal C.

If you short the meter out entirely (B open), the reading will go to zero, with 7.5uA flowing through the short.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7TS3w.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Your circuit in schematic format.*

> How would I redirect the charge to go from contact A to contact B, instead of contact A to contact C (effectively shutting off the multimeter)?

You really mean how can I direct current (rather than charge). You can only direct current by connecting and disconnecting parts of the circuit. This is traditionally done with a switch but can be done with transistors and other "controllable" conductors.

If your purpose is to demonstrate resistors and switches, you could make a SPDT (single-pole, double throw) switch using thumbtacks as contacts and a paperclip as the switching element.

[image]

*Figure 2. SPDT drawing-pin switch example. [Source](http://198.185.178.104/iss/electricity/pages/a182.xml).*

Don't expect great results from the contact between the pins and the pencil lines.

Another dodgy possibility is to draw the switch element on paper, cut it out, turn it face down and use it as the switching element.